# Paginating id's in a key of a document in firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a user model as:

```
User Document
  -- Following id's array
     -- Following id1
     -- Following id2
     -- Following id3
        ....... 
     -- Following idn
```

Now the problem is that I want to get the following list of a user. I am not clear about how to perform pagination for the same.

Like if I fetch the initial array of following and get the documents of the same with pagination, then how will I manage the pagination when the following list changes in real time.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Managing pagination in a realtime updated list from Firestore is not a trivial matter, and in general not even a solved problem(it's fraught with edge cases). That's also why the Firebase documentation on [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) uses one-time `get()` operations, instead of realtime listeners. 

Unless you've already started an implementation and have a specific problem with it, I think this is a bit too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I am with @FrankvanPuffelen on this being a bit to broad. Something to keep in mind though, is your app knows the range of data it's showing - for example suppose you are displaying followers 10-19. If you're using a listener and something changes *outside that range* then your app can simply ignore it. Likewise if it's something within that range you can re-calculate in code by updating your datasource and re-displaying. There are a LOT of cases where that simply won't work but it depends on the use case (e.g. it's too broad)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
My main problem is that I have document id's of the user's followers stored in an array that is in user document, that will change whenever follower changes. Now the firebase listener cannot be applied to a specific field, rather it is applied on whole user document. So my confusion here is to deal with the pagination related to an array field in a document. How will the comparisons be efficiently performed in this case that which id's are changed, whenever document has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paginating a snapshot listener is only "straightforward" with the right kind of data. For example, if the data is sorted by a timestamp and any change to data requires a change in this timestamp then any change to data would be seen in a change to the first page which really simplifies things. Then all you would effectively need to do is load the same number of results on screen that the user has already paginated through whenever there is a change in page one. This does require stringent serialization which may require the use of a semaphore (in the event updates overlap).

I think your data may actually work nicely here but I obviously don't know because I know very little of it. But if I understand your question correctly, you always have the complete array in hand whenever it changes, which is a big advantage. The array also comes sorted from Firestore (Firestore sorts arrays "by element") which is nice since paginating data requires a consistent order (no need to sort on the client).

So if I understand your use case correctly, place a snapshot listener on the array (on the document that contains the array). When you first get the array (which is already sorted), grab the first `n` elements of the array (the first page) and then render those documents on screen. Then when the user loads the second page, grab the next `n` elements of that array (which is still sitting on the client) and render those documents. And so on and so forth.

Now, if there is a change to data then the snapshot listener will give you a new array (with the same sorting). If the user has two pages rendered on screen then you must grab the first `n x 2` elements from the new array and re-render those documents on screen. And there are four cases to account for (not including edge cases like competing updates):

1. there is a new element in the array that should be rendered on screen (i.e. it's on page 1)
2. there is a new element in the array that should not be rendered on screen (i.e. it's on page 3 and the user is on page 2)
3. there is one less element in the array that is not rendered on screen
4. there is one less element in the array that is already rendered on screen

Your task is to determine how you want your app to handle these four cases. And it's all rather straightforward, right? For example, when the snapshot listener returns a new array with a new element that should not be rendered on screen or one less element that was never rendered on screen, you don't need to do anything. But in the event the new array contains one less element that is already rendered on screen, how do you want to handle this? Do you just want to remove that item or remove it and fill it with a new item to keep the pages full? And how you build the mechanism to do this can be done in a number of ways. And if a new update comes in before you finish this update, it could cause unwanted side effects which is why I suggested the possible need for a semaphore. There is a lot to consider but this is where I would start and it is most certainly doable depending on how ambitious you are.

Comment: Hello @liquid
First of all, thank you for your reply. Really appreciate it :)

My main problem is that I have document id's of the user's followers stored in an array that is in user document, that will change whenever follower changes. Now the firebase listener cannot be applied to a specific field, rather it is applied on whole user document. So my confusion here is to deal with the pagination related to an array field in a document. How will the comparisons be efficiently performed in this case that which id's are changed, whenever document has changed?

Comment: @ShivaniBajaj do you care about any other data updates in this document or is the snapshot listener on this document only there to listen to this array?

Comment: I do care about another data updates as well.

Comment: Then can you simply not only perform this update to the UI when the array changes? Before updating the UI, check to see if the new array is different from the currently-rendered array. Swift allows for this operation very easily if the contents of the arrays are themselves equatable, such as strings.

Comment: I am getting your point. Will try it out. Thank you for your help :)